# Can't start git in WebStorm after upgrade to MacOS Sierra

Tags: webstorm

After installing Sierra and starting WebStorm for my project, I'm getting an error that it can't find the git executable. I'm given the opportunity to 'fix it', and navigate to the file in `usr/bin/git`, but it won't run. In my terminal I ran `which git` and it returns `usr/bin/git`.

How can I get it started?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem in Mac OS Sierra version 10.12 solved after running xcode installation with following code from terminal:

xcode-select --install

Comment: This also worked after installing MacOS Mojave and having Git return there error the OP posted about. `xcode-select --install` from the terminal worked like a charm. More troubleshooting steps are here, if you have to go further than that: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/macos-mojave-invalid-active-developer-path

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reinstalling git 2.10.0. The executable switched location to /usr/local/git/bin/git